# Schema Generator for ApacheCayenne classes

Tags: java, graphql-java

I'm trying to use SPQR to generate GraphQL schema from a Cayenne generated class.
Cayenne class looks like this

```
public class MyCayenneClass {
  public static final Property<Integer> A_PROPERTY = Property.create("aProperty", Integer.class);
  public static final Property<Integer> ANOTHER_PROPERTY = Property.create("anotherProperty", String.class);

  public void setAProperty(Integer aProperty) {
      writeProperty("aProperty", aProperty);
  }
  public Integer getAProperty() {
      return (Integer)readProperty("aProperty");
  }

  public void setAnotherProperty(String anotherProperty) {
      writeProperty("anotherProperty", anotherProperty);
  }
  public String getAnotherProperty() {
      return (String)readProperty("anotherProperty");
  }
}
```

As the class isn't a simple POJO, SPQR throws an exception and the schema isn't generated.

```
Error: QUERY_ROOT fields must be an object with field names as keys or a function which returns such an object.
```

What's the best approach here (without modifying the cayenne class (i.e. annotating a method)?

GraphQLEndPoing.java

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/graphql")
public class GraphQLEndpoint extends SimpleGraphQLServlet {

public GraphQLEndpoint() {
    super(buildSchema());
}

//This method used SPQR
private static GraphQLSchema buildSchema() {
    GraphQLSchema schemaGenerator = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator()
            .withOperationsFromSingletons(myRepository) //register the beans
            .generate();
    return schemaGenerator;
}

 private static final MyRepository myRepository;

 static {
     myRepository= new MyRepository ();
 }
}
```

MyRepository.java

```
public class MyRepository{

private MyLibService libService;

 @GraphQLQuery
 public MyCayenneClass  find(Integer id) {
    List<MyCayenneClass> myList= libService.fetchById(new Integer[] {id});
    return myList.get(0);
 }
}
```

*FYI. If I declare the schema. Code will work just fine

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  find(id: Int): MyCayenneClass
}

type ConcContract {    
 id: ID
  aProperty: Int
  anotherProperty: String        
}
```

Comment: Please first give it a go with the latest version of SPQR (0.9.6 at this moment). This class seems like it should work just fine. I'll try it later and give you more info. Btw, this is not a top-level class you're registering with SPQR, right?

Comment: I don't what to do with this class... Where are writeProperty and readProperty coming from? Can you provide a more complete example, as I'm absolutely unfamiliar with Cayenne? It's important to see if this class is used as an input or output, and also how the schema generator is configured.

Comment: They are Cayenne classes. i.e. cayenne-server-4.0.B2.jar. I'updated the code

Comment: GraphQL commented was my fault when pasting the code here. My first guess about the issue is that SPQR could not find the getters/setters for the properties in the class. i.e.
Property<Integer> A_PROPERTY
//get/set
public void setAProperty(Integer aProperty) {
      writeProperty("aProperty", aProperty);
  }
  public Integer getAProperty() {
      return (Integer)readProperty("aProperty");
  }

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to replicate... The error claims nothing was mapped on the top-level. Maybe put a break point in `AnnotatedResolverBuilder#buildQueryResolvers` and check if it returns anything. If you keep having issues, ping me on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/leangen/graphql-spqr) and we can look into it deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SPQR's perspective, this isn't really different from a POJO, as SPQR cares only about the types.

By default, for all nested classes (`MyCayenneClass` in your case), everything that looks like a getter will be exposed. For top-level classes (`MyRepository` in your case), **only annotated methods are exposed by default**. And at least one top-level method must be exposed, otherwise you have an invalid schema.

The error, as it stands, just means not a single top-level query was discovered. I see the `@GraphQLQuery` annotation is commented out. Is that intentional? With the default config, this would not expose any query.

You can register a different `ResolverBuilder`, e.g. `PublicResolverBuilder` (or your own implementation/extension) if you want to expose un-annotated methods.

E.g.

```
generator.withOperationsFromSingleton(new MyRepository(), new PublicResolverBuilder())
```

This would expose all public methods from that class.

Here's a slightly simplified example I tried with v0.9.6 and seems to work as expected (I know you're using a rather old version from the error text).

```
public class MyRepository {

    @GraphQLQuery //not commented out
    public MyCayenneClass find(Integer in) {
        return new MyCayenneClass();
    }
}

// extends CayenneDataObject because I don't know where to get the 
// writeProperty and readProperty from
// but shouldn't change anything from SPQR's perspective
public class MyCayenneClass extends CayenneDataObject {
    public static final Property<Integer> A_PROPERTY = Property.create("aProperty", Integer.class);
    public static final Property<String> ANOTHER_PROPERTY = Property.create("anotherProperty", String.class);

    public void setAProperty(Integer aProperty) {
        writeProperty("aProperty", aProperty);
    }

    public Integer getAProperty() {
        return (Integer)readProperty("aProperty");
    }

    public void setAnotherProperty(String anotherProperty) {
        writeProperty("anotherProperty", anotherProperty);
    }

    public String getAnotherProperty() {
        return (String)readProperty("anotherProperty");
    }
}
```

There's many more customizations you can apply, depending on what you end up needing, but from the question as it stands, it doesn't seem you need anything extra...

To override the `ResolverBuilder` used for nested classes, you have 2 options.

1) Register it globally, so all nested types use it:

```
generator.withNestedResolverBuilders(customBuilder)
```

2) Or per type:

```
.withNestedResolverBuildersForType(MyCayenneClass.class, new BeanResolverBuilder())
```

But this is very rarely needed...

Comment: Using 0.9.1, when building the schema
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:559)
 at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:480)
 at io.leangen.graphql.util.ClassUtils.getCommonSuperType(ClassUtils.java:396)
 at io.leangen.graphql.metadata.strategy.query.DefaultOperationBuilder.resolveJavaType(DefaultOperationBuilder.java:58)
 at io.leangen.graphql.metadata.strategy.query.DefaultOperationBuilder.buildQuery(DefaultOperationBuilder.java:33)
 at io.leangen.graphql.generator.Opera

Comment: Will try with 0.9.6

Comment: Found the issue (its on my side). 0.9.6 gives better error msg.
Caused by: io.leangen.graphql.generator.exceptions.TypeMappingException: Multiple methods detected for operation "XYZ" with different return types. Types found: [boolean, java.lang.String]. If this is intentional, and you wish GraphQL SPQR to infer the most common super type automatically, see https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/wiki/Errors#operation-with-multiple-resolver-methods-of-different-types
 at io.leangen.graphql.metadata.strategy.query.DefaultOperationBuilder.resolveJavaType(DefaultOperationBuilder.java:122)

Comment: @Graciano Ah, I see. There's a ton of improvements and bug fixes in each release, so make sure you always stay up to date.